# "directed-acyclic-graph" is a tag synonym for "dag"

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Dag is exactly an abbreviation for directed acyclic graph. For now, there are [74 questions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dag) tagged [dag](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dag), while only [7 questions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/directed-acyclic-graph) tagged [directed-acyclic-graph](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/directed-acyclic-graph). Since I have no enough score in [dag](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dag), could someone with enough score please suggest [directed-acyclic-graph](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/directed-acyclic-graph) as a [dag](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dag) synonym?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since these tags are clearly duplicates, I've merged [directed-acyclic-graph](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/directed-acyclic-graph) into [dag](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dag) and made the former a synonym of the latter.